# Facebooker not logging in on server (works locally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker

I have these settings in my facebooker.yml file:

```
app_id: <app id>
secret: <secret>
api_key: <same as app id>
canvas_page_name:
callback_url: http://beta.mydomain.com:80/
pretty_errors: true
set_asset_host_to_callback_url: true
```

When I try to log in with FB I get the FB login popup, it logs in to FB in the background but my app does not log in. Same thing works fine locally with `callback_url: http://localhost:3000`. Any ideas?

*Update: also tried* `callback_url: http://localhost:80` *on server with no success*

Comment: The scope maybe? Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. What do you mean by scope?

Comment: The scope specify the permissions you want to have granted, like the ability to see the person friends or to post on his/her timeline.

Comment: I see. Actually I fixed it by changing the settings in the facebook apps page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sound stupid: the Site URL in the FB App settings was localhost:3000. I needed to set the correct domain. Although it now won't work on localhost, but that's another issue...

Answer (score -1):

When you registered you app on facebook. What address did you put as your callback url?

Comment: What, you created an account to repeat what I had just written in my answer?